# net of indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Hi everyone I was reading Dudley's book and I'm having problems with the following.

If $X$ is uncountable, show that there is a net of indicator functions of finite set converging pointwise to the constant function $1$, and also the net cannot be replaced by a sequence.

My idea was to use the set $\Lambda=\{A\in 2^{X}: A \text{ finite }\}$  partially ordered by set inclusion as the directed set, i.e, $A\le B \iff A\subset B$.  So define the net $\{1_A\}_{A\in \Lambda}$ But from here I'm not completely sure of how to show that this converges to $1$, because Dudley at this point never defines the pointwise converges. I think that is sufficient to show that for any nbhd of $x$ there is some $A\in \Lambda$, s.t. for $B\ge A$ we have $1_B\to 1$  but this is easy since we can considere $A= \{x\}$ and all the finite subset and this implies that $1_B \to 1$

Any idea? Am I totally out of track?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to work with $\Lambda=\{ A\subset X: A \textrm{ finite}\}$. Then everything works fine: Fix $x$. Then $\chi_B(x)=1$ for every $B\supset \{ x\}$ (trivially), verifying the pointwise convergence $\chi_A\to 1$.

Comment: @chistianremling: Ok I almost got it. That was my first idea of directed set. Only one thing in this case the pointwise convergence is simply to say that taking any arbitrary point $x$, there is some $A\in \Lambda$ for which $1_B\to 1$ for any $B\ge A$, in this particular case $1_B= 1$. Sorry the author doesn't define the pointwise convergence yet. Anyway is trivial to see why the net cannot be replaced by a sequence, since the union of elements must be countable always we can choose one point which is not in it.

Comment: Pointwise convergence of functions $f_{\alpha}$ simply means that for any fixed $x$, the net (or sequence, in other situations), $f_{\alpha}(x)$ converges.